# How to change variables inside a class at runtime?

Tags: python

Follow-up question on my previous question.

After I got the circle to show up properly, I wish to be able to move that circle now with keyboard input.

Since it is a class I am trying to change I must have an instance so that I change the same instance of the class all the time, and I do have one.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

#Display
display_width, display_height = 800, 600
screen_center = int(display_width * 0.5), int(display_height * 0.5)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

#Clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xPos = int(display_width * 0.5)
        self.yPos = int(display_height * 0.5)
        self.color = blue
        self.radius = 15
        self.width = 0

        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.xPos, self.yPos), self.radius, self.width)

def game_loop():
    player = Player() #PLAYER CLASS INSTANCE

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.color = blue # THESE COLORS ARE MAINLY HERE FOR DEBUGGING
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.color = red # THESE COLORS ARE MAINLY HERE FOR DEBUGGING

                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    pass
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    pass

        #Background
        screen.fill(white)

        #Draw everything in order, each drawn object will be drawn beneath the next drawn object.
        player

        #Update
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
```

So whenever I press the left key for example, the xPos inside the class must change so that my circle moves.

Comment: You're already changing instance attributes of your `player` class instance with `player.color = blue` and `player.color = red`. You can do the same with `xPos` with something like `player.xPos = player.xPos + 1`

Comment: Well the colors does not work :) It is there for debug to see if it works.

Comment: So it looks like your player class draws itself once, within its own `__init__` method. Within your event loop (the `while running:` loop), it doesn't look like you ever draw the player. So you update the values of the player, but if you never draw it again you will never see the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing your player class to make it have a separat emethod for drawing itself:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xPos = int(display_width * 0.5)
        self.yPos = int(display_height * 0.5)
        self.color = blue
        self.radius = 15
        self.width = 0

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.xPos, self.yPos), self.radius, self.width)
```

Then inside your main loop, call player.draw() after you've done the screen fill:

```
#Background
screen.fill(white)

#Draw everything in order, each drawn object will be drawn beneath the next drawn object.
player.draw()
```

Now the player object wont draw itself when it's created, instead it will be drawn during every iteration of your main loop.

Comment: But what is it that makes that work and not the one Before?

Comment: See my comment above: " 
So it looks like your player class draws itself once, within its own __init__ method. Within your event loop (the while running: loop), it doesn't look like you ever draw the player. So you update the values of the player, but if you never draw it again you will never see the updated values"